# What is the transformation of $g(x)=2x$ with respect to $f(x)=x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering what the transformation from $f(x) = x$ to $g(x) = 2x$.  Is this  a vertical stretch, vertical compression, horizontal stretch, or horizontal compression?  Thanks a lot in advance, folks!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it in two ways, actually. It is both a vertical stretch *and* a horizontal squish!

On the other hand, going from $x+1$ to $2x+2=2(x+1)$ can only be seen as a vertical stretch, while going to $2x+1$ is only a horizontal squish.

The difference has to do with whether you're affecting only the *input* -- that is, $x$, or the *output*, i.e. the whole right hand side of the function definition. For the example you give, $x$ *is* the whole right hand side, so there's no difference between the two.

Comment: I assume you meant to say going from $x + 1$ to $2x + 1$ is only a horizontal squish.

Comment: Thanks, a lot.  That had been confusing me because I didn't think the answer could be multiple things!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graphing calculator you can plug in both functions and see what the difference is. The since the constant is bigger than 1 it will vertically stretch the graph.